# can Python 'and' return None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking at some code which apparently runs, as nobody has complained about it, but am well confused by what they have written:

```
if a and b is not None:
    # do something
```

I have always thought of the 'and' operator as something which returns True or False, now am starting to doubt myself.. What else would it return, a number..  It is probably not pythonic, but am I missing something - how can someone write something like that?

Comment: Empty list evaluates to `False` doesn't it? It's not a `NoneType` I thought?

Comment: I'm looking at the answers.. Somehow I read it  `if (a and b) is not None:` and imagined brackets which possibly are not there.

Comment: @cardamom Correct, they are not there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python 3]: Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, **from lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most binding)**.
>
> ```
> ...
> and                                                 Boolean AND
> not x                                               Boolean NOT
> in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==        Comparisons, including membership tests and identity tests
> ...
> ```

The fact that ***is not*** comes **after** ***and***, means that it will be evaluated **before** ***and*** (both might not be evaluated at all, due to *lazy evaluation* - thanks @NickA for the comment), so the expression is equivalent to (adding parentheses for clarity):

```
if a and (b is not None):
```

Also, according to [[Python 3]: Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an [if](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) or [while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below.

your ***if*** statement is perfectly *OK* (produces a *bool*).

Examples (using [[Python 3]: class **bool**(*[x]*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)):

> ```
> >>> bool(0)
> False
> >>> bool(100)
> True
> >>> bool([])
> False
> >>> bool([0])
> True
> >>> bool(None)
> False
> >>> bool({})
> False
> >>> bool({1: 1})
> True
> >>> bool(None is not None)
> False
> >>> bool(1 is not None)
> True
> >>> bool(2 and 1 is not None)
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks, those two links are very helpful. I wish people could just put in brackets though. That 'Operator precedence' table is worse than what we had to learn in arithmetic in school. I notice that PyCharm does not object if you do put in the (redundant) brackets, so it can't be bad style, not sure if it is good or bad.

Comment: You're welcome. Well the operators precedence are in a table for every language (including the arithmetic), I'm not sure whether there is a user friendlier manner that they could be expressed as. I didn't see notes in the *PEP8* that would forbid redundant parentheses, but I think that it would make sense to have them where things are unclear.

Answer (score 5):

It means if `a is Truthy` and `b is not None` and not what you thought it meant i.e. `a and b is Truthy`

```
a = 999
b = None

if a and b is not None:
    print("a is True but b is None")
else:
    print("a is True and b is not None")
```

Comment: Minor titbit, `a is True` ==> `a` is truthy

Comment: @NickA Ha, yess

Answer (score 2):

The code above means:

If `a` (is truthy), AND `b` isn't `None`, then `#do something`.

Answer (score 1):

In this code, you evaluate `b is not None` first, which is a boolean.

And then `a` is implicitly converted into a boolean 
(For a `list`/`dict`, `False` if it is empty. For a number, `False` if it is 0)

then `and` is evaluated which always return a boolean.

Answer (score 1):

It is most certainly valid.

When we take a variable which has been assigned a value and perform the **AND** operation with another variable with a null (in python - None), the **AND** operation results in a **None**. Hence, the check can be made. To make my point clear, please refer below.

```
a=2;c=None; b=11
if a and c is not None:
    print("T")
else:
    print("F")
```

and

```
print(a and c)
```

results in **None**

and

```
print(a and b)
```

results in Non-null value - in our case **11**

Comment: The output of your last statement there was interesting.. I really thought that 'and' returned only True or False but looks like it works a bit differently, you just don't normally notice as it is in an 'if' statement.