# Why are 'and/or' operations in this Python statement behaving unexpectedly?

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have a conceptual question about Python. This is the code

```
list1=['assistant manager', 'salesperson', 'doctor', 'production manager', 'sales manager', 'schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher']
sub1 = "teacher"
sub2 = "sales"
ans=[]

for item in list1:
    if (sub1 and sub2) in item:
        ans.append(item)
```

Here, I expect the list to be empty as none of the items satisfy the condition `if sub1 and sub2 in item:` But when I print the list I get the **output#1** as this

```
>>> ans
['salesperson', 'sales manager'] # I expected an empty list here
```

Also, when I use `or` instead of `and` as given below

```
for item in list1:
    if (sub1 or sub2) in item:
        ans.append(item)
```

the **output#2** I get is

```
>>> ans
['schoolteacher', 'mathematics teacher'] # I expected a list of words containing sub1 or sub2 as their substrings
```

I saw a similar looking solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108493/can-python-and-return-none), but it does not exactly solve my problem. Both the times I get a result which I do not expect while using `and` and `or`. Why is this happening during both these operations?

Comment: `(sub1 and sub2) in item` what will be the result of the expression in the brackets? That will be checked against `item`.

Comment: Change `(sub1 and sub2) in item` to `sub1 in item and sub2 in item`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can Python 'and' return None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54108493/can-python-and-return-none)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`("teacher" and "sales") in "salesmanager"` do not mean the same in Python and in English.

In English, it is synonynous to `("teacher" in "salesmanager") and ("sales" in "salesmanager")` (which Python would understand as you thought it should, and evaluate to `False`).

Python on the other hand will first evaluate `"teacher" and "sales"`, because it is in parentheses, and thus has higher priority. `and` will return the first argument if falsy, otherwise the second argument. `"teacher"` is not falsy, so `"teacher" and "sales"` evaluates as `"sales"`. Then, Python continues to evaluate `"sales" in "salesmanager"`, and returns `True`.

Comment: So far as I know, all languages give parentheses first priority, not just Python.  But you are correct in explaining what Python returns for  `( X  and Y )`

Comment: You might want to suggest `any` and `all` for this pattern.

Comment: @NeilG I thought about it, then figured there's a big disparity between the level where precedence needs to be explained, and the level where someone can understand generators and functions like `all`, and that it would just confuse the asker (i.e. a person who would be ready to benefit from that would not be looking for this question in the first place).

Answer (score 6):

The `and` and `or` operators don't do what you think they do.  Try breaking up your expressions:

```
if sub1 in item or sub2 in item:

if sub1 in item and sub2 in item:
```

The `and` operator evaluates its left-hand operand and, if the result is truthy, returns the right-hand operand, otherwise the left-hand operand.

The `or` operator evaluates its left-hand operand and, if the result is falsy, returns the right-hand operand, otherwise the left-hand operand.

So, in your first expression evaluates as follows:

```
(sub1 and sub2) in item
("teacher" and "sales") in item
("sales") in item
```

which is not what you expected.

Similarly for your second expression:

```
(sub1 or sub2) in item
("teacher" or "sales") in item
("teacher") in item
```